# How can I make a bulma table responsive?

Tags: css, html-table, responsive, bulma

I am using the Bulma CSS framework and specifically I am trying to make the table in it responsive.

I have tried giving it a `width: 100%;` and applying `overflow-x: auto;` but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the demo: http://104.236.64.172:8081/#/pricing

Code:

```
<div class="panel-block">
    <table class="table is-bordered pricing__table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Travellers</th>
                <th>Standard</th>
                <th>Delux</th>
                <th>Premium</th>
                <th>Luxury</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Per Person Cost</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Extra Person <br>
                    (> 12 yrs)
                </td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Extra Child <br>
                    (> 12 yrs)
                </td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Cost</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
                <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.pricing__table {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem, as it is described.

Comment: Just look at the demo. The problem's there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could wrap the table in a container, and apply the `overflow` property there instead.

Also, you can use the `is-fullwidth` modifier on `table`, instead of declaring `width` in the CSS.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/c9g373uu/1/)

```css
.table__wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table__wrapper">
  <table class="table is-bordered pricing__table is-fullwidth">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Per Person Cost</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Extra Person <br> (> 12 yrs)
        </td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Extra Child <br> (> 12 yrs)
        </td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Total Cost</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
        <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Update as per comment**

In your case, you also need to add the `width` property to `.pricing`

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/c9g373uu/2/)

```css
.table__wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.pricing {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-block">
    <div class="pricing">
      <div class="table__wrapper">
        <table class="table is-bordered pricing__table is-fullwidth">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Per Person Cost</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Extra Person
                <br> (> 12 yrs)
              </td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Extra Child
                <br> (> 12 yrs)
              </td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Total Cost</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
              <td>₹ 70,523.90</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. There is a problem when I apply this solution to the running website here: http://104.236.64.172:8081/#/pricing
Maybe it has something to do with flexbox or the fact that I am using a table inside a `panel-block` of bulma. It doesn't seem to work. Can you help me debug it? Just apply these changes to the live site using chrome inspector and see for yourself.

Comment: Are you able to change the markup? Try wrapping the table in its own `div` like in the snippet.

Comment: I did. You can check for yourself. In the inspector. Just right click the `<table>` node and `Edit as HTML`. Then you wrap the table in a `div`.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could edit the HTML like that.. learn something new every day! I got it working by removing `flex` on the `panel-block`. I think you'll need to restructure your HTML. It would be easier to help if you edit your question with the relevent HTML and CSS, thanks

Comment: Did you remove `display: flex` from the `panel-block`? It didn't fix for me. Can you elaborate on the changes you made?

Comment: BTW it's working just fine without `.is-fullwidth` on `table`.

Comment: Bulma has a built-in solution https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/table/#table-container

Answer (score 9):

use `.table-container` in parent div:

```
<div class="table-container">
  <table class="table">
    <!-- Your table content -->
  </table>
</div>
```

https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/table/#table-container

Comment: Right, just don't wrap the .table-container in a `columns` neither `column` class

Answer (score 4):

I found a [great alternative](https://flaviocopes.com/css-responsive-table/) that turns horizontal elements into vertical ones:

```
@media
only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
    display: block;
  }
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
  td {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 200px;
    margin-left: 150px;
  }
  td:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: -150px;
  }
  td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Option"; }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Description"; }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Type"; }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Default";}
}
```

If you don't need the headers, remove the `td:before` modifiers.

Comment: This is awesome!